Rollup : Error: end must be greater than start, with vite
I have a vueJS application, configured with vite. When I run the vite build, the build run perfectly.
But during the build of my docker image with the same vite build. I get this error Error: end must be greater than start, which seem to be thrown by rollup. I don't have rolllup configuration in my application though.
I have :

tried to change the node version outside my docker and in my docker.
installed globally the rollup package in my docker.
changed my vite config.


Are you using the same node version on your laptop as in your docker container?

Yes, I have answered my own question for the community and for documentation purpose because the link was not so obvious for me

I have check my packages, I have seen I have few webpack packages. Removing them and upgrading the other packages made my docker build ok.
Not really sure why, because the build was ok few times ago.I guess the webpack packages caused conflict with vite.
